# Why does Visual Studio not have a simplistic approach to recreating/exporting the "whole" of a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

As the title says, why? I want to go about being able to transfer or save my c# form project in such a manner that I can still open it at different locations. I'm aware that conflicting frameworks or Visual Studio versions will prevent this from happening, although I can assure that both my .NET and VS versions are the same about both residences.

In general, I have an error where visual studio will open the project, however, when I want to edit any portion of my form, I notice that all files under Form1.CS (including From1.CS) have a lock and  cannot be found. I realize that the project follows a path in which these files are notable to the IDE, is there a way I can go and direct Visual Studio to these "missing" files? Or perhaps is there measures I need to invoke prior to saving my project on my original PC?

I am approaching the end of my first programming year and I would like to clarify any errors that I may be held accountable for, or anything I can do to prevent such errors so that I don't have similar confrontations later. I'm quite aware after researching similiar claims that the complexity of what I need to accomplish may be beyond my current understanding. Nevertheless, help is help indeed, and I will attempt to make the best of it that I can.

Also, I have exported templates with no luck as the zipped file still does not contain my form files.

Comment: You are doing something wrong.

Comment: Files under Form1.cs are missing? This sounds... suspicious. Generally speaking, a WinForm class might have the primary class file `Form1.cs` and its designer file `Form1.designer.cs`, but they'll reside within the *same* directory. Maybe you could show a specific example in more detail? Some screen-shots from Visual Studio and Windows Explorer perhaps?

Comment: Surely, I can post some screenshots. In the mean time, regarding that such files are in the same directory -- On my original computer, the files Form1.cs and From1.designer.cs ARE in the same directory as eachother, but not remotely close to the project folder itself. (which, for some reason is contained on an entirely seperate drive) Might this have an affect on how my secondary computer searches for, what would be, the missing file? When I attempt to load the project on my secondary computer it actually is refferencing the drive of my original computer.

Comment: There are literally thousands of people successfully doing what you've described.  Maybe you can provide more detail.

Comment: @Araien Yes, the fact that your project folder and source files related to that project are on different drives will have a **big** impact on its portability. Did you make the project yourself? You're free to associate project files from any path, but it's your *own responsibility* to maintain a logical hierarchy. (P.S. Source files being on different drives to the project file is an exceptional circumstance and would need exceptional justification to be considered anything other than outright illogical.)

Comment: Yes, thank you Snixtor! When you said "same directory" it hit me. I'm not sure how they ended up so far off... but that's a different question in itself. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically if the files under `Form1.cs` are missing, you failed to copy over `Form1.designer.cs` and/or `Form1.resx`.

In general projects are structured such that all referenced source files are in or under the project's root folder.

If you follow that approach, copying the entire folder with subfolders is sufficient to ensure that all source files are available to the project (or better... checking all source files into version control in or below the root directory, and checking them out / getting them on the new computer).

You may still run into missing components necessary to build the project if it references assemblies that are not available on the new computer (e.g. things installed in the GAC, or referenced via a path).  If you use [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) to manage third-party dependencies, it will download missing packages on the new computer for you.

Comment: Thank you. Re-read your post, exactly what I'm looking for. It was an error regarding my refferences.

Comment: If this solved your problem don't forget to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what exactly you're doing to transfer the files between your computers, but it seems like you could benefit from a [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system like [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com), or [Git](http://git-scm.com) and a matching web provider to store your source.

Answer (score 0):

I never have any problems with my codes portability and I simple put all my code in Dropbox and sync it from computer to computer that way.

So long as all your references are set to copy to the project folder and you aren't using any hard coded paths, this shouldn't be a problem.